# Google Tag Manager Debug Preview - Not working properly

Tags: web, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a problem in Google Tag Manager on Preview mode.

Everything is connected and there's no issue with the tag installation. However, the system doesn't so my clicks and it doesn't update the summary with the tags that are fired.

In the screenshot, this is all I see, despite clicking on the website multiple times. This only happened recently as it was working the week before.

Hopefully, someone can assist.
[image]

Assistance with the GTM bug

Comment: Can you create a trigger `all click` and no other condition and tags then check the preview again?